# Appending multiple POST data to aa php email

Tags: php, email

```
mailsend = mail("myemail@gmail.com", "this is the email subjct"
   , "this is the email body", "From: renault@cupon0km.com\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php");
print("$mailsend");
```

Im sending an email with PHP but how can i add into that email body the following variables?:
(these values come from a previous from POST)

```
$_POST['CustomFields_17_5'];
$_POST['CustomFields_12_5'];
$_POST['email'] ;
$_POST['CustomFields_16_5'];
```

EDIT: format is not required

Comment: This is very easy to do with string concatenation, as well as the fact you don't say what format you want your included fields to be in; should it be a raw email with those fields printed as-is, or should it be formatted better? You need to add more detail to your post.

Comment: `"this is the email body $_POST[CustomFields_17_5] $_POST[CustomFields_12_5] $_POST[email] $_POST[CustomFields_16_5]"`

Comment: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @JamWaffles no format is required, what would you suggest?

Comment: @sebas `"this is the email body {$_POST['CustomFields_17_5']} {$_POST['CustomFields_12_5'}] {$_POST['email']} {$_POST['CustomFields_16_5']}"`  You may want to consider using htmlspecialchars() on the data though, in which case just assign each post value to a variable and you can just put the variables in the string like this: `"This is the body Email: $email Custom: $custom_17_5"` etc

Comment: @sebas *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: @drew Unless it's an HTML email, there's no point in HTML escaping the content.

Comment: @deceze its plain text, no format required. Your solution doesnt work becuas it only adds the email variable and not the rest, any idea?

Comment: Then there is no "rest". What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you?

Comment: @deceze it gives me: var_dump(Array)

Comment: @deceze here is the var_dump please check it out:
http://pastebin.com/h49NtutY

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6927/discussion-between-sebas-and-deceze)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$body="this is the email body and these are my variables: ".$_POST['CustomFields_17_5']
    ." and ".$_POST['CustomFields_12_5'];." etc.";
mailsend = mail("myemail@gmail.com", "this is the email subjct"
   , $body, "From: renault@cupon0km.com\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php");
print("$mailsend");
```